# HTML Page with a C Server?

Tags: html, c, http

If you have a server that you made in C running and then connect to it as a client with a web browser, how would you display an HTML page to the client?

I tried just writing html code to the client, but it didn't work, the page is blank.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to feed the HTML ASCII data back over the socket to the client.  So you could setup a buffer with a HTML response header that a typical browser would look for as follows:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 512

char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];

char html_body[] = "<html><head></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>\r\n";

char* temp_ptr = buffer;

int num_chars =  sprintf(temp_ptr, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
temp_ptr += num_chars;

num_chars = sprintf(temp_ptr, "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n");
temp_ptr += num_chars;

num_chars = sprintf(temp_ptr, "Content-Length: %d\r\n", strlen(html_body));
temp_ptr += num_chars;

num_chars = sprintf(temp_ptr, "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n");

num_chars = sprintf(temp_ptr, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
temp_ptr += num_chars;

num_chars = sprintf(temp_ptr, html_body);
temp_ptr += num_chars;

int total_message_length = temp_ptr - buffer;

int bytes_written = write(socket_file_descriptor, buffer, total_message_length);

//... do any error-checking on your write to the socket ...
```

You should definitely look into [more information on the HTTP protocol](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPHypertextTransferProtocolHTTP.htm) in order to setup a proper web-server that responds correctly to web-browsers expecting standardized responses.

Comment: The `Content-Length` should be the length of the content after the header, not the size of your buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Your C program must return HTML to your browser by printing to stdout. The very first few lines must contain at least this following header:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

After this one header line, follow it with two blank lines and then your HTML content. You can include other HTTP headers as you wish prior to the two blank lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    printf("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
    printf("<html><head><title>C Program</title></head>\n");
    printf("<body><h1>It Works!</h1></body>\n");
    printf("</html>\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The \r\n sequence is actually required by the HTTP standard.

Comment: so it just goes to stdout rather than being sent to the client?

Comment: I guess @jbruni wrongly assumes you use CGI, which you don't as being stated in the question.

Comment: If you're writing a cgi script you output to stdout, but if its a full web server it needs to write to the socket.

Comment: I just tried writing it to the socket and for some reason the only thing displayed on the page is "Content-Type: text" without the quotes. If I don't use the Content-Type header then it doesn't display anything though.

Comment: Try: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n\r\n`, then the HTML content.